# Upload one photo to Facebook fanpage

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, offline

I'm using this tutorial http://pastebin.com/WpJmPYAi, and with some changes I can upload a photo to my fanpage.

But, I  want to be able to upload when I'm logged out from Facebook. In my website, I need to be able to upload images to the fanpage without my account login.

Is this possible?

For example, I think: Is there any way to do this:

```
$page_info = $facebook->api("/".$fanpage."?fields=access_token");
```

Without a facebook accounts logged in, only with my app and accounts data.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a stored `access_token` using the `Facebook::setAccessToken($access_token)` method.

See the PHP SDK documentation for details: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-setAccessToken/